# How to link data with a single key and multiple values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hey all looking at the data below I am trying link the values of the first columns that are the same with their corresponding values. I also tried linking them in Access like a database but i will be writing a script with this and can not access outside information like jsons with script.gs. So I need to do this natively in my google sheets.

```
typeID  BPO materialTypeID  Mat quantity
180 Proton S    34  Tritanium   58
180 Proton S    35  Pyerite 23
180 Proton S    37  Isogen  1
181 Depleted Uranium S  34  Tritanium   118
181 Depleted Uranium S  36  Mexallon    1
181 Depleted Uranium S  37  Isogen  2
182 Titanium Sabot S    34  Tritanium   58
182 Titanium Sabot S    35  Pyerite 64
182 Titanium Sabot S    36  Mexallon    1
183 Fusion S    34  Tritanium   162
183 Fusion S    35  Pyerite 3
183 Fusion S    37  Isogen  3
184 Phased Plasma S 34  Tritanium   164
184 Phased Plasma S 35  Pyerite 17
184 Phased Plasma S 37  Isogen  3
185 EMP S   34  Tritanium   204
185 EMP S   35  Pyerite 17
185 EMP S   38  Nocxium 1

Here is what I am trying to end with :

181 Depleted Uranium S  34  Tritanium   118
    Depleted Uranium S  36  Mexallon    1
    Depleted Uranium S  37  Isogen  2
182 Titanium Sabot S    34  Tritanium   58
    Titanium Sabot S    35  Pyerite 64
    Titanium Sabot S    36  Mexallon    1
183 Fusion S    34  Tritanium   162
    Fusion S    35  Pyerite 3
    Fusion S    37  Isogen  3

etc......
```

Comment: I also tried to print out all the columns using a query. =QUERY(A11:E25,"select B,C,D,E where A contians 182")

Comment: Or this =CONCATENATE(QUERY(A11:E25,"select B,C,D,E WHERE A ="),A3)

Answer (score 1):

Data from A2 to E19 for example:

```
=arrayformula( {left(A2:A19&"",1000* transpose(split(join("","1," & rept("0,",countif(A2:A19,"=" & unique(A2:A19))-1)),",",true,true))),B2:E19})
```